# Homework Question: Need just a hint for the base case to throw an exception for a recursive binary search when a word doesn't exist

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

When searching for a word that doesn't exist in the array that is passed, the function will cause a StackOverflow before I can throw the custom exception. I do not want to hardcode mid at an average count of how many iterations it takes before it "should" find the word.

```
 public int recSearch(String[] words, String wordToFind) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    if (count == 0) {
        low = 0;
        high = words.length - 1;
    }
    count = 1;
    super.incrementCount();
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (mid <= 0)
        throw new ItemNotFoundException("Item not found");
    if (words[mid].equals(wordToFind))
        return mid;
    else if (words[mid].compareTo(wordToFind) < 0) {
        low = mid + 1;
    } else {
        high = mid - 1;
    }
    return recSearch(words, wordToFind);

}
```

Comment: hint: instead of trying to find the exact match, try to find the closest value. This guarantees you termination.

Comment: Hint: What will `low` and `high` be when you're 100% certain the word is not found?

Comment: low will be 1 value less than high I believe. Debugging again rn


Edit:
Nevermind, I'm incorrect, but it did terminate the word that did not exist, but also words that did exists but weren't found until the last iteration possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the hints help guide me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the questions correctly, but if you mean the condition `mid <= 0` doesn't throw the exception and the functions continue to operate until it causes a StackOverFlow then simply use this condition instead: `low >= high`

The thing is if while you're binary searching the array you either increment low or decrement high, so if the word you're searching for is not in the array, low will just continue to be incremented until it passes the value of high.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.